# Can I connect a 90 degree tee to my plumbing that goes straight down?

Tags: plumbing, pvc, sewer

I currently have a kitchen sink on the first floor which leads to a vertical pipe (illustrated in black). I would like to connect a bathroom sink to the same vertical pipe (illustrated in orange). Can I do this using a 90 degree tee or does both pipes have to be connected separately to the vertical pipe? [image]

Comment: Is there a vent pipe anywhere? Generally you would connect two separate sinks to the same vertical pipe using a double fixture sanitary tee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two 90 degree sanitary tees for this, one for each sink. You'll never be able to unclog the drain with a tee as you've got it shown.

[image]

If space is limited, you can use a double fixture fitting like the one below.

[image]

Comment: I wont be able to drain unclog the vertical pipe you mean? If I would install a inspection in the vertical pipe? I also considered two tees, but it is up in a ceiling and space is very limited.

Comment: @MLEN  Yes, you won't be able to unclog the vertical stack from either sink.

Answer (score 2):

For reduced clearance, use a "double wye" or a "double fixture fitting" and cap off the vertical (the opening at the top).

You need the sweep for the clean-out and to prevent water crossing over or inhibiting flow when both sinks in use.

[image]

Image: https://www.pmmag.com/articles/102042-riding-the-plumbing-roller-coaster-direction-changes-in-a-system-give-water-a-wild-ride